# validation of recommendation system

Tags: recommender-system, precision-recall

we have system that rank the best 3 products from inventory of 20 products. Order of 3 product selected doesn't matter. one way to validate is based on recall and precision.

But each product has different price points. I addition to recall we need to understand the impact of revenue. How to perform this validation(we have training and validation data set)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the idea of a cost matrix. In many cases we give the same error to false positive and a false negative. However, sometimes we have different goals.

In your case, assigning to a false negative the profit from the product sounds reasonable. The cost of a false positive might be based on the reduced probability that a customer with many options will buy any of them.

Suppose that you compute the costs of the errors (usually, estimations are good enough) and you decided that for **your use case** a false negative costs 10 times more than a false positive.

You do the validation as usual, (e.g., doing cross validation and getting a confusion matrix). Now you should just weight by the costs when measuring the samples.